# Login with Twitter Error Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth, rubygems

This code is to authorize the login page from twitter and request token and secret token are stored in the yml db in config. Whenever I run this code, it gives the follwing error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

See the image and code below

http://s2.postimg.org/4wshzrwrd/err.png

```
class TwitterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def login
    oauth.set_callback_url("http://#{request.host}#{":#{request.port}" unless request.port == 80}/twitter/finalize")

    session[:request_token] = oauth.request_token.token
    session[:request_secret] = oauth.request_token.secret

    redirect_url = oauth.request_token.authorize_url
    redirect_url = "http://"+redirect_url unless redirect_url.match(/^http:\/\//)
    redirect_to redirect_url
  end

  def finalize
  end

  private

  def oauth
    @oauth ||= Twitter::OAuth.new(APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_key], APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_secret])
    # @oauth ||= Twitter::Client.new(:consumer_key => APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_key], :consumer_secret => APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_secret])
  end

end
```

And Please download the code from https://www.dropbox.com/s/134v3yas6ze7q05/app.zip!

Comment: Looks like `APP_CONFIG` is not defined.

Comment: APP_CONFIG is defined in .yml db which can be found in config. Please download the code and play.

Comment: I'm not going to download your code. People on here generally won't. We don't know if that is Ruby code, or a self install virus. We would rather not risk it being the latter. Do you have a `:twitter` key defined in your app config file?

Comment: There is only a file named app_config.yml which contains 
:twitter:
:consumer_key: key
:consumer_secret:  key

Comment: Have you done anything to verify that `APP_CONFIG` is actually defined?

Comment: Here is the environment.rb code where I am calling APP_CONFIG
    # Load the Rails application.
    require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

    APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.open(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/app_config.yml", "r").read)

    # Initialize the Rails application.
    Myauth::Application.initialize!

Answer (score 1):

You might have missed to add your consumer_secret and  consumer key in your APP_CONFIG file which is APP_CONFIG.yml